# Link form in Vue component to Django model

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, vue-component

I have a template/html form inside one of my Vue components. How do I link this to my django model? I know how to do this in the case of linking a form made using django's built in forms, but I am not after that, I wish to link my vue form to my django backend.

Comment: You'll need to send an HTTP POST to your backend via an API mostly.

Comment: @kissu what would that mean? In my app.vue file, besides a form, I have a script that successfully makes a GET request. However, I am looking to now use the fetch api among other things so that when my vue form is submitted, an object is created in my django backend.

Comment: Yep, use fetch to send a post to your backend. A frontend and a backend work through an API.

Comment: But how does this exactly work? My fetch request currently is a url/path that contains data in dictionary/list form which is what I have used in my GET method. After fetching this url/path, how would it change my django database in a POST method? Because when I fetch in a POST method, I would get an error saying I am not returning a httpobject

Comment: SO is not a place to fully explain such principle. I recommend that you check how to make a CRUD implementation with your Django backend. Then it's a matter of sending the appropriate payload to your backend (you choose the format you want to received at the end of the day). Once you receive it on your router -> controller, you can call your model and update your database.

Comment: Yes, I will look into all of that. However, it is difficult to do so when my main concern is with linking my frontend which is ultimately responsible for sending any POST request for my backend to deal with. There seems to be very little resources on using a Vue form to make a POST request/update backend as you have mentioned.

Comment: Your Vue app is "inside" of your Django or do you have your backend as an API + your Vue app as an SPA? There are no resources on how to make POST requests for the single reason that it's not related to Vue itself. It's some common principle for vanilla JS. You can check [that one](https://javascript.info/fetch) or use axios too, a bit quicker to use.

Comment: Yes, I am using Vue/VueJS as an SPA and Django as a backend (with models related to a form my front end contains).

Comment: Yep, all good so. Follow the usual way of doing a CRUD + Frontend communication.

Comment: @kissu if you have a form in a vue component, do you know how to import into views.py?

Comment: Don't say blocked on the idea of a form, you clearly can use anything (like a JSON object). And it's totally unrelated to any Python views since you told me it's used as an SPA.

Comment: views can be used to retrieve data and spa as in the page isnt being refreshed

Comment: Views can bring up data yeah, but here you have your backend separate. So rather create a GET endpoint on Django and fetch it with either fetch or axios from Vue's side.